# javac1.8 class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classnotfound

I have installed two jdks - jdk 1.5 and jdk 1.8.
I have following Ant build.xml config file :

```
<target name="compileCustomSrc">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" source="1.5" target="1.5" >
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="C:/lib/">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Before installing jdk1.8, Ant invoked from Eclipse compiled all sources successful. But now, I have following error message:

```
Class not found: javac1.8
```

My JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_16
```

and set in Eclipse JRE to 1.5. Does Java 1.8 set some configs during installation?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
Class not found: javac1.8
```

This error is known to happen with Apache Ant versions less than 1.9.0 - which aren't compatible with Java 8. If you're using a version of Ant < 1.9.0, you should update to a 1.9.x release.

Here is the related bug report: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53347

Btw, if you just want to compile with Java 8, but don't need to compile any actual Java 8 syntax, then you can pass the following argument to javac as a *workaround*, which would allow you to continue using an older version of Ant:

```
-Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7
```

Comment: I ran into this issue, and the given flag (`-Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7`) works when passed directly to `ant` as well.

Comment: Kristian answer is correct, we could add -Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7 when generating the ant-launch config in eclipse see <https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409358>

Comment: I found the [code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/compilers/CompilerAdapterFactory.java?r1=1037667&r2=1345316&pathrev=1345316&diff_format=f). They're testing whether you're using Java 1.3 or below. Old, old code from over a decade ago. Because of this, Ant breaks each time Oracle comes out with a new 1.x version. Ant already requires 1.4 or higher. They should just remove this check from the code.

Comment: @ David W - why the hell didn't they add support for Java 1.9 and 2.0 so the changes work for the next 6 or 8 years. Java 9 will be out soon, and everything is going to break again....

Comment: The bug was fixed in 2012 for Eclipse's Ant 1.9.0 but Ant in Eclipse Kepler (2014!) is still at 1.8.4 and so this problem still exists. Is this upgraded in Luna or are we still waiting? (I find Eclipse's Web site utterly useless for any kind of proper change tracking and knowing what versions of what plugins went into what releases; is this there anywhere?)

Comment: Thanks, just hit this with ant on MacOS 10.8 while testing for backwards compatibility for an app.  Workaround was plenty to fire off the build with 1.7.

Comment: Note - You can get past this error by using ant 1.8.2, if you need to stick to 1.8.X versions for some reason. I tried it with 1.8.4, and it failed, but worked fine with 1.8.2

Answer (score 14):

As a follow-on to Kristian Holdhus's answer (marked as correct), you can instead use the `compiler` attribute on the [Ant javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). Setting `compiler="modern"` should be both backward (as far back as 1.3) and forward compatible.

This avoids the need to set the Java System property named `build.compiler`. Only in the absence of explicitly setting the `compiler` attribute on the `javac` task, will Ant use the value of the `build.compiler` as a fallback.

Comment: I certainly upvoted Kristian Holdus' answer. However, I found this to be a better solution for my situation. By forcing the callers to add a -D param, we are making it difficult to ship the build.xml to external users. We also need to provide additional usage instructions, which are always lesser the better :)

Comment: its working, showing notes when building `[javac] warning: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\lib\rt.jar(java/net/ConnectException.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac]   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.` etc

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue. I had JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME set correctly.  I also had Ant > 1.9.

What I did to fix it is go into Eclipse to Window -> Preferences. Expand Ant and select Runtime.  By default the Classpath tab should be selected and on the right hand side there is a button called "Ant Home".  Click this button and double check it is pointed to your Ant folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_16
```

Your JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set to the Java 1.5 installation hence 1.8 binaries (like `javac`) are not found.
Set them to the Java 1.8 installation and you should be fine.

Comment: But I don't want to use jdk1.8. Why Ant try to use 1.8 compiler with this settings?

Comment: Run the Ant build with "Run As" > "Ant Build..." then open the "JRE" tab and select the "Runtime JRE" you want to use to run the script.

Comment: The "javac" task can generate byte code for older vms, See the "target" attribute in the doco: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html Java 1.5 cannot generate bytecode for later VMs.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it with Eclise and got the same error **Class not found: javac1.8**

I verified the ANT version on my system

**>ant -version**

> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015

When I tried to run the build.xml from the command prompt, it worked.
Then I checked that in the Eclipse, it was referring to the older version of the ANT.

I simply edited the ANT HOME path in the Eclipse and it worked from here also. :)

Below is the image from where need to edit the ANT Path in the Eclipse.

1. Right click on the build.xml file
2. Run as
3. External tool configurations
4. Select the classpath tab

Now change the ANT Home path from here.

[image]

Comment: What did you change the ANT Home path to?

Comment: Hi @IgorGanapolsky Earlier the  Ant version path was for Ant 1.8 which I updated to the latest Ant version 1.9 as shown in the image above. And it worked.  Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Update Ant to 1.9.x release as Java 8 in incompatible with Ant versions less tha 1.9

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the other solutions, but none worked. I finally found an approach that worked for me in Eclipse, follow these steps:

1. Right click on the ant task name, e.g. `myBuild.xml  in the ant window.
2. Choose `Run As | External Tool Configurations`.
3. Then on the JRE tab, choose Separate JRE: Java JDK7 or whatever your java 7 is named.
4. Hit Apply and then Run.

Your ant task will be executed, and will build correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the other solutions, but none worked. I finally found an approach that worked for me in Eclipse:

- Right click on the ant task name, e.g. "compileCustomSrc" in the `ant` window.
- Choose `Run As | External Tool Configurations`
- Then on the `JRE` tab, choose `Separate JRE: Java SE7` or whatever your java 7 is named, then hit `Apply` and then `Run`.

Your ant task will be executed, and will build correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Update Ant to 1.9.x release as Java 8 in incompatible with Ant versions less tha 1.9 or after the comand put -Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7, see the below:

ant release -Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7

Answer (score 0):

you can download and unzip ANT 1.10 on your system and try to chnage the ANT home in eclipse for your project to 1.10. It should work, Read this for more details. http://devops-badal.blogspot.com/2017/02/class-not-found-javac18-issue-while.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue while building the war through ANT is also related to java version miss match in build.properties files as build.XML tries to use the java version mentioned in build.compiler property

check whether build.compiler property is same as intended java version.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a newer version of eclipse, which includes a newer version of Ant in the plugins directory. Then, copy the Ant jar into the older eclipse's plugin directory. Eclipse will automatically point to the newer version of Ant. This worked for older Kepler with newer Mars2 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I was able to solve it within the build.xml by setting a property.

```
<property "build.compiler=javac1.7">
```