# How to compile a netbeans java project into a runnable file

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

I've just made a project in Java with Netbeans and would like to run it on a computer without Netbeans or the JDK. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Jar file in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681876/how-to-create-a-jar-file-in-netbeans)

Comment: You have to create a JAR or a WAR file out of it which can be used to run/deploy the application in a standalone environment. Generally there is an option to save the project as a JAR/WAR file.  Look into that. Its pretty straightforward. :)

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but I am getting this error when I do it `Class not found: javac1.8`
@user2339071

Comment: Do you use Ant to build your project? Possibly this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702626/javac1-8-class-not-found) explains that error you get.

Comment: @entropy: Check the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702626/javac1-8-class-not-found. You need to pass some arguments while compiling it. Check the link.

Comment: @mattias: Lol. I posted the exact same link.. :D . Also if the OP is using Ant, perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442621/ant-class-not-found-javac1-8 will also help. Probably some issue mentioned here.