# Can I add a newer version of Apache Ant to an older version of Gradle?

Tags: java, ant, gradle

I am currently running `Gradle 1.7` but wish to build my project in `Java 8`, I seen that it is necessary to run at least `Ant version 1.9` to use `Java 8`, I currently only have `Ant version 1.8`, when trying to build I get the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702626/javac1-8-class-not-found).

How can I download `Ant version 1.9` and integrate it so that Gradle uses the *newer version* of `Ant` when building my project?

I have downloaded `Ant 1.9.6` and replace the ant and ant launcher `JARS` in the gradle libs folder but now when I run gradle -version I get:

```
Cannot locate Jar for Module Ant
```

Comment: This is an option but I want to try this first. Surely there must be a way to add a newer version of ant to gradle?

Comment: Ok I will try the gradle uprade, what is the first version of Gradle compatible with Java 8?

Comment: At this point I detach, that is a 5 second google.

Comment: I cant find the correct answer on google, do you not know?